# Mixture of power-law distribution

Tags: distributions, mixture-distribution, power-law, application

I have two large sets A and B of (integer) numbers, both obtained with two different (and unknown) probability distributions $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$. 
A (also large) set C contains a proportion $p$ of elements sampled from $\rho_A$ and a proportion $1-p$ sampled from $\rho_B$, hence $\rho_C = p\ \rho_A + (1-p)\  \rho_B$.

I have access to the three sets A, B and C and I want to estimate $p$.

The catch is, the distributions $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ seem to have a *power-law tail*. So normalization is impossible, I can't compute the mean... I don't know the exact form of the distributions either.

> How can I extract the value of the mixture coefficient $p$ from my three populations $A$, $B$ and $C$ ?

Comment: I work with a similar problem.  Can the integers be thought of as ratios or as something similar to a count of times x exceeds y?  I ask because this may give you a clue as to the cause of the underlying distribution.

Comment: @DaveHarris It's not the case, they correspond  to the number of clones in a cell population to be precise

Comment: You definitely have a power law.  I will post an answer later.  I am in a restricted location and have limited access.

Comment: Sorry, still no computer.  Does the amount of food impact the mutation rate?  Also, if you thought of the count of mutations as $x_{t+1}=\beta{x_t}+\epsilon_{t+1}$, even though $x_{t+1}$ and $x_t$ are not independent, are the errors independent?

Comment: Your question is unclear: if the two distributions $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ are completely determined, the coefficient $p$ can be estimated by an EM algorithm. If  the two distributions $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ are themselves parameterised, a modification of EM will work.

Comment: The reason I ask about food is that it will skew the distribution.